# varied vs. various

Tags: word-usage

I would like to use 'varied' in the following way

```
The users have access to varied computing platforms
```

by which I mean to say, some members have access to high end platforms and others only low end platforms.

"Various" doesn't seem right here :

```
The users have access to various computing platforms
```

which seems to mean that each member had access to a variety of platforms.

Does my use of "varied" work as I intend here?

Or perhaps this is better :

```
Users have varied access to different computing platforms
```

Comment: Can you please link to a dictionary entry where *varied* carries the sense of *one-to-one mapping*? I haven't come across this use of *varied*. The natural sense of your first example is that the members could access a *heterogeneous* set of platforms (e.g. Apple, Windows, Linux, etc).

Comment: @Lawrence I don't have a dictionary entry, but was only guessing that 'varied' meant what I wanted here.

Comment: ‘Varied’ doesn’t carry the one-to-one connotation you mentioned. Is that an important part of the word you seek? That is, are you looking for a word that carries the sense of a one-to-one mapping where each element of the range (the kinds of platforms, in your example) is unique?

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom "variety" doesn't really work here.   I want to imply a sense of "constraint".    And there could be more than two (desktops, clusters, supercomputers, etc).  But not everyone has access to everything.  I'd like to keep it short, and not spell out each type of platform, but definitely convey the sense that some "only" have access to X, while others might have access to Y.

Comment: Why the down vote?  I am new to this forum ...

Comment: Not my downvote, but it’s unclear whether the 1-to-1 aspect is part of what you’re looking for.

Comment: @Lawrence I changed my post - one-to-one wasn't really what I was after.   But it sounds like 'varied' doesn't have the intended meaning here either.    Bummer.   I kind of liked it!

Answer (score 1):

*Varied* carries the sense that the platforms are different, but it doesn't automatically suggest that the difference is high-end *vs* low-end.

> **varied** *adjective*
>   Incorporating a number of different types or elements; showing variation or variety.
>   ‘The concert will include a varied programme with music to suit all tastes.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/varied)

You can also say that the members had access to *various* computing platforms, which pretty much says the same thing.

If you want to emphasise that some members had access to one portion of the installation and other members may have had access to different portions, you might apply *varied* to the access instead:

- We installed a range of equipment from low-end workstations to high-end supercomputers. Members were granted **varied access** to the equipment.

I've changed *had* to *were granted* to avoid ambiguous parsing (*had varied* could imply that members changed their own access).

Comment: In fact, I think I going to use something like :  "Users have varied access to different compute platforms".   I hope this better conveys the sense that some only have access to desktops, whereas others may have access to supercomputers.   Again, I don't want to get too specific (I am not describing an experiment), but just want to get across the idea that our solution works for different platforms.  Hm... maybe I should just say that.

Comment: @Donna Looks like we were thinking the same way. :)